# I tried switching from my Intel GPU to my AMD GPU, and failed

Tags: 16.04, intel-graphics, amd-graphics, vgaswitcheroo, switchable-graphics

I have an "AMD Radeon R5 M330" GPU and an "Intel HD Graphics 5500" GPU on my PC.

I did a check which GPU is in use:

```
lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+\:.+(\[\S+\:\S+\])/' | grep VGA
```

It printed only my Intel GPU.

Did the following:

```
sudo su
echo ON > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
echo DIS > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

Ran this again:

```
    lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+\:.+(\[\S+\:\S+\])/' | grep VGA
```

But I got the same output as before.

Same after rebooting the PC.

**Note:** vga_switcheroo is enabled, as `sudo ls -l /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` prints:

> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 май  3 17:10 /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch

Answer (score 0):

I have almost the exact same setup as your PC. I got it to work with PRIME.

Run `DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"` as shown [here](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Hybrid-Grafikkarten/PRIME/). It should show the AMD GPU. Now you should be able to use your dGPU by prepending `DRI_PRIME=1` to every program. (And yes you have to do it manually because it cannot change it automatically)